# Robots.txt with mutltiple domain sitemap entries

Tags: seo, web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt, google-crawlers

Our website has many domain names like:

```
example.co.uk
example.in
example.co.eg
...
```

So in `robots.txt` there should be an entry that shows where our sitemap file is located.

**So my question is:**

We have many sitemap files per each domain, so how in a single `robots.txt` file we can put these entries respectively for each domain?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Why it's off topic? Isn't it a not subjective programming question? You can check the answer below to make sure that this question is aligning well to the help center rules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the same robots rules for all domains, place your single robots.txt into the root and put all sitemap links into it.
I think the sitemap links would look like

`http://www.example.co.uk/sitemap.xml
http://www.example.in/sitemap.xml
http://www.example.co.eg/sitemap.xml`

Or you can establish a construction like

`/robots/co-uk.txt
/robots/in.txt
/robots/co-eg.txt`

put into them according sitemap links and deliver them dynamically according to user country with

`<ifModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^UK$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/co-uk.txt [L]
</ifModule>`

For this your should have mod_geoip or ip2location installed. If using ip2location replace `GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE` with `IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT`.